# Upload, store and load images

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, backend

I have a fundamental question. I'm working on several projects developing backend and frontend with node, react and react-native. Sometimes I have to upload, store and reload images. I found a way to upload images to a cloud service and load them later in my frontend. But now I have the situation that I don't want to store the images in a cloud service instead I want to store the images in my own database. Since I use a framework in my backend that don't support types like BLOB the only way to store a image is to convert the image to a string like base64. Now I'm facing some problems:

- Images above 2MB seems to be too large
- If I send a POST request to store a image I get an error that the payload or something like this is too large
- If I try to console log my base64 string the browser often hang up
- If I try to copy paste the base64 string for example in a JavaScript file as a comment it don't shows me the full string instead I found at some point a ...

So it seems to me that this approach is not fitted for real world applications. So what I want to ask is, how big players handle this Image workflow? For example if I open instagram or a shopping app, this apps maybe loads hundreds of images in seconds. Or if I upload a image to instagram, how is this done in the background? Do they convert the images to string?

I already failed by sending a simple POST Request with a image of 5Mb size converted to a base64 string.

Thank you in advance for some helpful tips.